# Firebase authentication, MainActivity calls itself onBackPressed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to understand authentication with Firebase in Android. Currently the authentication itself is working like charm. I have a `LoginActivity` and a `MainActivity` which gets called if a user successfully authenticates.

This is my `LoginActivity`:

```
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
EditText mEmailEdit;
EditText mPasswordEdit;
Button msignInButton;
TextView _signupLink;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userID", user.getUid());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };

    mEmailEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    mPasswordEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);

    msignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    msignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validate(mEmailEdit.getText().toString(), mPasswordEdit.getText().toString())) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mEmailEdit.getText().toString(), mPasswordEdit.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("userid", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // disable going back to the MainActivity
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

public boolean validate(String email, String password) {
    boolean valid = true;

    if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        mEmailEdit.setError("Email is not valid");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEmailEdit.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
        mPasswordEdit.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mPasswordEdit.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

And this is my `MainActivity`:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

So my issue is that after a user successfully authenticates and the `MainActivity` gets called, if I press back to **close** the app or return to my homescreen. What happens is that the `MainActivity` calls itself again. So after pressing back once I see another `MainActivity` popping up. After I press back on the new one again, it finally closes and goes back to the homescreen or whatever app I was in before.

I kind of fixed this by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the `manifest` in the `activity` tag of the `MainActivity`, but I still do not know why the `MainActivity` called itself again when `android:launchMode` was not set and I really do want to understand it.

On another note I would also really like to know what the AuthStateListener is for. I don't understand why I would need this in my application. As I `finish();` the `LoginActivity` as soon as the user signs in, the `AuthStateChanged` event never gets called. So am I using it wrong or is it actually kind of useless?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press back, LoginActivity is called. However, since you are still logged in to Firebase, the AuthStateListener will fire with user != null and so the main activity gets called again. Depending on if you want the user to log in each time, you should override onBackPressed() in MainActivity and call the firebase logout function.

The firebase login persists across starts/restarts of your app, and the authstatelistener handles this.

Comment: So if I would remove the `AuthStateListener` this would not happen anymore?

Comment: It should not. However, note that the AuthStateListener is google's recommended way of handling sign in/sign out.

Comment: Would it be better to just sign the user in on button click and then start `MainActivity`in the `AuthStateListener`? By the way your answer was perfectly correct. I will mark it as soon as I can.

Comment: Look at my edit - I think my previous answer was wrong. And yes, you should start the MainActivity in the AuthStateListener as that will also handle the use case when the user did not sign out of the previous session.

Comment: Yes, as I was changing it, I noticed that I just called it twice.. That's why there is no endless loop. The way to go is still starting the `MainActivity`in the `AuthStateListener`. Thanks for pointing that out. Everything works as expected now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```